# Processing XML to prepare for map reduce

Tags: xml, mapreduce

I have a large (~120Mb) pretty printed xml that is pretty printed with newlines.  I want to prepare it for a map reduce parser.  Is there a way to do this without loading it all into memory on a single machine?

Sample input is

```
<mediawiki xmlns="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.6/" version="0.6" xml:lang="en">
  <siteinfo>
    ...
  </siteinfo>
  <page>
    <title>File:Wiki.png</title>
    <id>1</id>
    <text xml:space="preserve" bytes="358">==Summary==
{{Information
|attention=
|description=The logo of [[OurWiki]]. Cropped
}}</text>
  </page>
  <page>
  </page>
  <page>
  </page>
    </mediawiki>
```

and the desired output is

```
<page><title>File:Wiki.png</title><id>1</id><text xml:space="preserve" bytes="358">==Summary=={{Information|attention=|description=The logo of [[OurWiki]]. Cropped}}</text></page>
```

Where we only keep the Page elements and remove the newlines inside of the element.  I would prefer to do this in Scala or Python, but other languages are OK too.  Of course, there could be mal-formed page elements too.  I can skip these.

Comment: 120MB is not all that large in today's world of 8GB systems being common.

Comment: That is very true.  This is the first version.  Soon to scale up a few orders of magnitude.

Comment: This is easily accomplished with a streaming event-based processor in Java or any other language that supports event-based XML parsing; or a stream-capable XSLT engine.